# Eclipse - file name in code hover/pop-up

Tags: eclipse

When one hovers over a piece of code, say function call, Eclipse pops out a small window that contains this function declaration. Is it possible to make that window display name of the file in which function is defined?

Comment: I doubt, but pressing F3 should open up the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so, you can use the links in the popup to quickly show the class in question, so that's almost the same thing.